# command condition sometimes integer sometimes string

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-script

I want to execute this condition

```
while [ $(cat /path_of a file/) -eq 1 ]
```

The condition is only correct if

```
$(cat /path_of a file/)
```

is an integer and not a string !

How can I overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `=` operator, like `[ $(cat /path_of a file/) = 1 ]`. It compares string representations of both arguments so it will work in all cases.

Using `-eq` instead of string comparison may be preferable in some cases (`[ 01 -eq 1 ]` is true while `[ "01" = 1 ]` is not) but in most cases it's just more dangerous. If, on the other hand, you really need integer comparison, you should use @Gnouc suggestion.

Comment: better use quotes: `[ "$(cat file)" = 1 ]` -- if the file is empty, you'll get a syntax error otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Variable in bash is untyped. If you want the condition to always get evaluated with integers, you can use `delcare -i` to make variable always an integer. From `bash manpage`:

```
declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
.....
-i     The variable is treated as an integer; arithmetic evaluation
       (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION above) is performed  when the variable
       is assigned a value.
```

So your example becomes:

```
declare -i number
number="$(cat /path_of a file/)"

while [ "$number" -eq 1 ]
```

A note that if you have `bash` version 4.x, you should use new test `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`.

Comment: `[[` is available in older versions of `bash` as well.